# Enter insert to insert mode from function

Tags: vimscript, search, replace

I want to create function that search for selection and then automatically replace selection with given text. Something like `*Ncgn` but with custom movement (not exactly word only).

My current function is:

```
function! s:VSetSearch(type, ...)
  let temp = @@
  if a:0
    silent exe "norm! gvy"
  elseif a:type == 'line'
    silent exe "normal! '[V']y"
  else
    silent exe "normal! `[v`]y"
  endif

  let @/ = '\V' . substitute(escape(@@, '\'), '\n', '\\n', 'g')
  call histadd('/', substitute(@/, '[?/]', '\="\\%d".char2nr(submatch(0))', 'g'))
  let @@ = temp
endfunction

xnoremap <Plug>(vsearch-change-selected-forward) :<C-u>call <SID>VSetSearch(visualmode(), 1)<CR>:set hlsearch<CR>cgn
xnoremap <Plug>(vsearch-change-selected-backward) :<C-u>call <SID>VSetSearch(visualmode(), 1)<CR>:set hlsearch<CR>cgN
```

But I would like to have also mappings in normal mode that would work on operators, but I have no idea how to accomplish that.

Comment: I'm not sure if I get exactly what you're trying to do, but `ciw` is identical and shorter than `*Ncgn`

Comment: With one exception. `ciw` change current word and when I `.` it changes it again. When I use `*Ncgn` then selected word resides as current search, so `.` will change next occurrence of that word. Example https://asciinema.org/a/2nv6rrsu06mzajk9hslxd78t7. So this works like `:s///gc` but is much faster for simple search and replace.